# getMaxTransceiveLength() from HostApduService

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I am doing bi-directional data exchange via NFC with `nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode()` on one side and `HostApduService` on the other side, see [Host-based Card Emulation example](https://github.com/grundid/host-card-emulation-sample).

I want to know the maximum transceive length. I easily can do that on the reader side,

```
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);
        int maxLen = isoDep.getMaxTransceiveLength()); // 65279 on Samsung GS5
        ...
    }
```

But how can I do that on the `HostApduService` side?

EDIT: It cannot transmit and/or receive getMaxTransceiveLength() bytes even in one direction, it looks like some bits of the array length are cleared.

Comment: I am currently having the same "problem". Did you found a solution?

Comment: @cherry-wave nope; instead, I found out that all this stuff is even worse than I expected, and having a hard-coded constant is not the last problem. So use a constant that works, you will have to write code much worse than that. (I do not remember what it was, but it was absolutely counter-intuitive, the technical logic almost contradicted the impression that one could get from the docs.)

Comment: Yeah haha I know NFC is very interesting. What I did was read out the maxTransceiveLength on the CardReader side out of the tag and give it as parameter to the transceive command.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there currently is not equivalent to `getMaxTransceiveLength()` for the HCE side.You could, however, try to estimate the maximum possible length by repeatedly trying to transceive different lengths.

Typically, you can expect that Android devices in HCE mode are capable of transceiving at least around 250 bytes. See [Android 4.4 hce (host-based card emulation) "processCommandApdu" apdu length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23831830/2425802) and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69233